# Merge references into output .dll C#

Tags: .net, merge, ilmerge

I've trying to do this lately without sucess, I would appreciate new feedback to help me clarify things.

My project has the following structure.

References:

- DocX.dll
- PDFClown.dll
- PdfSharp-WPF.dll
- PdfSharp.Charting-WPF.dll

Classes:

- IDocument
- Pdf : IDocument
- PdfParser
- Text : IDocument
- Word : IDocument

Output:

- TextReader.dll

I've tried to merge using:

> ILMerge: Duplicate type 'Project.IDocument'
>
> ILMerge with /internalize flag: Duplicate type 'Project.IDocument'
>
> ILMerge with /allowDup flag: Adds a random number to spacename (e.g Project79859.Pdf), external project referencing says it cant find spacename even after changing it.
>
> Jeffrey Richter Method (http://bit.ly/bDPbh3): Seems to work only for executable output.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

PS. Target project works as it is now, with the 5 dll's un-embedded, but specs require only 1 dll to be present.

Comment: Search for a definition of `IDocument` in all those assemblies. I assume someone was trying to be clever and use the same namespace/type name combo to make a wrapper transparent.

Comment: I presume you're trying to merge the 4 references into your output assembly? Are you able to show the full ilmerge command you're using?

Answer (score 1):

embed the assemblies to resource and when needed load them from memory using reflection.